# Is there a way to hide output in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to keep all of the code below but I would only like to output the application name? I need to have the where statement in the output. Is it possible to hide the output of anything after "APPLICATION NAME: $_ so that I don't see the output from $Requirement?

```
Write-output "APPLICATION NAME: $_ `r`n Requirement: $Requirement " | Where { $_ -notlike "*All_x64_Windows_10_and_higher_Clients*" };
```

Comment: What do you mean "need to have the where statement in the output"? Do you want the literal statement as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not familiar with PS, but with a bit searching an fiddeling this is what I came up with.

Write-output ("APPLICATION NAME: $_ `r`n Requirement: $Requirement " | Where { $_ -notlike "*All_x64_Windows_10_and_higher_Clients*" }).split("`r`n")[0]